# Vertica SQL: Histogram of counts from time series data with gaps

Tags: sql, time-series, histogram, vertica

I thought I know SQL quite well, until I wanted to create seemingly simple thing:

- an aggregated histogram that shows item counts by id;
- distributed in equal time intervals by 1 minute;
- histograms for all ids must have the same time intervals and slots;
- so if there were no entries in that time slot, gaps should be filled with 0;
- ordered by total count desc.

I suppose there must be some elementary aggregate function which allows to do this in Vertica, but here is the best I could come up with in SQL, and I really don't like what I have managed to come up with - especially for much data, this approach is really bad, because it will eat cosmic amounts of memory (notice the CROSS JOIN beast).

**Input Data:**

[image: Input Data]

Table of items(id which is repeating, created_at)

```
CREATE TABLE items(id int, created_at timestamp);

INSERT INTO items(id, created_at) VALUES (1, '2016-01-02 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO items(id, created_at) VALUES (1, '2016-01-02 00:01:01');
INSERT INTO items(id, created_at) VALUES (2, '2016-01-02 00:05:10');
INSERT INTO items(id, created_at) VALUES (2, '2016-01-02 00:05:12');
INSERT INTO items(id, created_at) VALUES (3, '2016-01-02 00:05:01');
INSERT INTO items(id, created_at) VALUES (3, '2016-01-02 00:05:04');
INSERT INTO items(id, created_at) VALUES (3, '2016-01-02 00:05:30');
INSERT INTO items(id, created_at) VALUES (3, '2016-01-02 00:02:05');
INSERT INTO items(id, created_at) VALUES (3, '2016-01-02 00:20:02');
```

**Expected Result:**

[image: Histogram]

**My Version of SQL Query That Does This:**

*(I am really ashamed now...)*

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    sum(a.count) AS total_count,
    agg_concatenate(a.count||',') AS histogram
FROM (
    SELECT
        i.id,
        times.ts,
        nvl(counts.count,0) AS count
    FROM (
        SELECT ts FROM (
            SELECT '2016-01-02 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP AS tm
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '2016-01-02 00:20:00'::TIMESTAMP AS tm 
        ) t 
        TIMESERIES ts AS '1 minute' OVER (ORDER BY tm)) times
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT id FROM items
        ) i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            time_slice(created_at, 1, 'MINUTE') AS ts,
            id,
            count(*) AS count
        FROM
            items
        GROUP BY
            1,2) counts ON counts.ts=times.ts AND counts.id=i.id 
    ORDER BY 1,2
) a 
GROUP BY
    a.id
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC;
```

**Other Possibilities Considered**

There is off course an alternative to write custom Vertica User Defined Extension in Java, C++ or other language, but before doing that, I really wanted to make sure I didn't miss some simple solution, how to do that.

Vertica is the kind of data base platform where one would expect such thing exists, just maybe I wasn't careful enough in reading the manual...

If you are an expert in Vertica or know better solution in plain SQL, would be nice to find that out.
Even if you know an existing the UDX for this, also would be helpful. Main thing - I want this to be calculated as close to data as possible.

Thanks!

Maris

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look bad. I don't know any any elegant workarounds for your histogram field:

```
agg_concatenate(a.count||',')
```

> Main thing - I want this to be calculated as close to data as possible.

That kind of concatenation is something I would have done in Excel or outside of SQL if needed, but I understand having to have special constraints on where the data is crunched.

Is the performance of the query really slow for your needs or something?